# Make only one dataGridColumn with autosuggest

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am making an **c# project** for a Grocery or a store. And there I have a **datagrid** in which I programmed the cells to auto suggest and it is working fine.

There is only one problem. I want that one column (for example the BARCODE Columns) in the datagrid to be a textbox with autosuggest only, and not all columns.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    string cnn = (@"Data Source=TaLy-PC;Initial Catalog=dbMarketi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn.ToString());
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Barcode FROM tblDepo", connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        {
            SqlDataReader drd = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (drd.Read())
            {
                // this.comboBoxEx1.Items.Add(drd.GetString(0).ToString());
                source.AddRange(new string[] { drd.GetString(0).ToString() });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    connection.Close();

    TextBox dgvEditBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (dgvEditBox != null)
    {
        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This a suggestion, try to separate your `AutoCompleteStringCollection` and your query for barcodes `Products`.

```
private AutoCompleteStringCollection source  = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            private void loadAutoCompleteStringCollection();
            {
                string cnn = (@"Data Source=TaLy-PC;Initial Catalog=dbMarketi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
                source.Clear();
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn.ToString());
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Barcode FROM tblDepo", connection);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    {
                        SqlDataReader drd = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (drd.Read())
                        {
                            // this.comboBoxEx1.Items.Add(drd.GetString(0).ToString());
                            source.AddRange(new string[] { drd.GetString(0).ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

            private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
            {
                TextBox dgvEditBox = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (dgvEditBox != null)
                    {
                        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
                        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                    }
                }
            }

            //If you want to reload the AutoCompleteStringCollection
            private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                loadAutoCompleteStringCollection();
            }
```

Comment: Thnx Spajce for the response and this works only for the first time. If I add this code it will work only for one time, after that again all cells will have the autosuggest mode.

Comment: I wanted to try your code that you wrote, but it shows me many errors. And the reason is becuase of this:

private source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

It doesnt accept it. In my code i have "var source...." but if I use it outside a class it doesnt accept Var variables. Also it doesn't accept the code you have written to me :( :(

Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: oh.. try my updated answer, `private source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection()` it should be like `private AutoCompleteStringCollection source  = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();` sorry for that.

Comment: I tried but it is still not working :( I don't know why, I tried the excat thing as you told me to do :(

Comment: i think you forgot to call `loadAutoCompleteStringCollection();` just place in your `Form_load event`

Comment: I did put the loadAutoCompleteStringCollection(); in the form load, and it is showin the autosuggest still in the other columns.
As i can understand there is somthing wrong with the if statemtn... it doesn't work as you think it should :( you have any idea? Please help me if you can, i really need to have this on my project

Comment: please check the `if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)`. try to figure out what is the ColumnIndex of Barcode column.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct.

What i would do to correct your code is that with your EditingControlShowing Eventhandler you basically saying, treat any column as a Textbox.

If you want to only treat the one specific column as a Textbox then run a check, something like this :-

```
 // EditingCOntrol Showing

    If(datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        TextBox dgvEditBox = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (dgvEditBox != null)
        {
            dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
            dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        }
    }


// public Object 

 public AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

Comment: i tried even your answer but it doesn't work :( it doesnt show me the autosuggestion :(

Comment: The only thing i would check is, your using the correct Column Index, I have stated 1, as an example, place a messagebox in your EditingCOntrolShowing EventHandler, that displays the datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex toString(), and make sure that when you click on the designated column, the index matches what is n your source code. Make sure you popuate your AutoCompleteStringCollection with values when you Initialise your Form.